# Can we have anonymous function inside defmodules?

Tags: elixir

Can we do Something like

```
defmodule EmailMatch do
    match_email = fn(id) -> Regex.run ~r/[a-zA-Z]+\s*\@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-z]+/, id end
end
```

and use it like:

```
EmailMatch.match_email("bdn@sdkj.net")
```

albeit above gives:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function EmailMatch.match_email/1
    EmailMatch.match_email("bdn@sdkj.net")
```

Comment: Since that code actually does work (or at least it compiles, anyway), you really need to clarify your question.  "It isn't working" isn't really a question that can be addressed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this code works, but you won't be able to access the function from outside the module or even from the `def`s inside the module. I guess that's what you mean by "this isn't working" as it compiles fine for me. You *can* call it from other expressions directly inside the `defmodule`:

```
defmodule EmailMatch do
  match_email = fn(id) -> Regex.run ~r/[a-zA-Z]+\s*\@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-z]+/, id end
  IO.inspect match_email.("foo@bar.com")
end
```

Output:

```
["foo@bar.com"]
```

If you want this function to be only available inside other `def`s in the module, you can use [`defp`](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules.html#named-functions) to define a private function.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I found this to be just a syntactic sugar and easier to do. Anonymous functions binding and calling by another variable isn't really something I've found in the docs.

```
defmodule EmailMatch do
  @moduledocs """
   matching email
  """
  def match_email(id), do:Regex.run ~r/[a-zA-Z]+\s*\@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-z]+/, id

end
```

I think I'll have to do with this.